# Searching database for specific row with sqlite.swift

Tags: database, sqlite.swift

I read a specific row in my database. I used the filter query but all I get is the following:

```
Table(clauses: SQLite.QueryClauses(select: (false, [SQLite.Expression<()>(template: "*", bindings: [])]), from: ("users", nil, nil), join: [], filters: Optional(SQLite.Expression<Swift.Optional<Swift.Bool>>(template: "(\"id\" = ?)", bindings: [Optional(6523)])), group: nil, order: [], limit: nil))
```

This is my query:

```
let query = users.filter(id == 6523)
print(query)
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, sorted the issue myself. I used the prepare function. See code below

```
let query = users.filter(id == 6523)
for user in try db.prepare(query) { 
   print("id: \(user[name])") 
}
```

Comment: im getting the error "id is unavailable in Swift".  Where is id declared before the query?

Comment: Cannot subscript a value of type 'Row' with an index of type 'Int'